# Problems using iPad and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, banshee, ipad

I have two probems using my iPad with Ubuntu. The first one is that I can download music from my iPad, but not upload it. The second is that... after the first connection, the iPad doesn't appears in the computer. What should I do?

My computer is a 64 bits Virtualbox VM running with 1.5 GB, inside an iMac 21'5'' Late 2009. I'm using Banshee instead of Rhytmbox.

My tablet is an iPad 2 32 GB Wi-Fi, with iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: Nobody knows how to solve it? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I can't sync the music with my iPad because DBVersion 5 is not supported in any way by Ubuntu.

2) It didn't appeared because there were problems between Virtualbox and the USB port.